# How can I remove or change the UIEdgeInset of these two UITableViewCellSeparators?

Tags: uitableview, uiedgeinsets

I have this UITableViewController, and I wanted to change the separators' edge insets. I have managed to change the ones between cells, but the two line I have shown in the image below is not changing.

The top one is the line just below the section header view, and the other one is (I suppose) the line just above the section footer view, but I have not added or changed the latter.

Many thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you get for using the **grouped** `tableView` style.
Anyways... since it seems you're using `-viewForHeader:`, you could easily switch to the **plain** `tableView` style.

This can be done via the **`IB`**:

[image: tableView Style]

or...
if you had instantiated the `tableView` programmatically  then something like:

```
UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:someRect 
                                                        style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

---

**NOTE:** Switching to the **plain** style will fill up any extra space with separators as if there're blank cells.
This is easily fixed by adding the following line in your `-viewDidLoad`... or wherever:

```
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];
```

---

**Now...**
If you complain that the section header doesn't move with the rows then, luckily since it seems you have only one section, you could make the section header, the `tableView` header instead.

Basically, don't use `-viewForHeaderInSection:` or `-titleForHeaderInSection:` and instead have this in your `-viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:theHeaderView];
```

**But...**
If you have multiple section headers and simply *hate* the feel of section headers floating over the cells then it seems you're out of luck and will have to stick to the grouped `tableView` style.

Comment: Hi @staticVoidMan Thanks for the answer, but if I change it to plain view, my custom UIVewCell is going to go berserk, so I was wondering if there is a way to use grouped tableview, and have the separators corrected?

Comment: @Septronic : honestly, I have not come across any way to disable the section separators in a grouped style so I am guessing the answer is "No" but... anyways, why would your custom `UITableViewCell` go berserk?

Comment: hmm, that'll make things complicated I guess! I will have to find another route!! :) I have implemented this round section effect, similar to how grouped sections used to look like. So when I change the style to plain, everything stops working and sizes/measurements and colours change.

Comment: @Septronic : hm... those separators are really irritating at times :/ ...anyways, best of luck :)

Comment: Lol, managed to sort those out. Got rid of the round rectangle and made a backgroundimage instead of changing the shape of the cell, not ideal but better than throwing my laptop out of the window! now I've got another problem though, do you know how to remove excess separators from the end of the table? I've got two extra separators underneath the confirm box as seen in the image. There's nothing there, as in sections or rows, yet those pesky separators are there!! I don't suppose you know why? Thanks for all your helps anyway! :)

Comment: @Septronic : haha but erm... 2 extra separators... in grouped style??

Comment: @staticVoicMan lol :) that was a grammatically incorrect comment :) got it all working bud. Thanks for all the help :)