# need footer added through storyboard to float at bottom of UITableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, footer

I have a UITableView with a tall header, many cells, and a footer. I add my footer through the storyboard: this makes it easy for me to create IBAction to buttons inside my footer. The problem is that my  footer is not floating. **I need the footer to float** at the bottom of the screen (except when the keyboard is showing, then I want it to show right above the keyboard). Right now my footer is the very last cell in my table, so that when there are many cells, the footer is offscreen. How do I fix my code so that the footer is aways floating at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: switch to `UITableViewStylePlain` style. check [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25649789/2857130) for quick reference regarding the `tableView` style

Comment: my style is plain. I never changed it in the Attributes Inspector

Comment: then it should float. it floats here, hm...

Comment: oh, wait a sec, you said you added it via the storyboard. it seems you have added a `tableView` footer and not a section footer. implement the `-titleForFooterInSection:` or `-viewForFooterInSection:` delegate method and that should float.

Comment: May be this topic will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047720/uitableview-make-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-screen

Comment: I did that (and its the current version of my code), but the problem now is that when the keyboard shows up, it hides the textField that is inside my "footer", as the footer does not move.

Comment: now that, my dear friend, is not ready made. What you can do is shift the `tableView` frame up by the keyboard height. once again... something along these lines: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19678064/2857130)